# What is to be done to fix Git log command failing from a Bitrise script

Tags: android, git, macos, bitrise

Consider:

```
git log --pretty="format: %s" master..HEAD
```

This is failing from a Bitrise script step with the below error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..HEAD': unknown revision or path not
>   in the working tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run below git commands before running the git log command mentioned.

```
git fetch --all

git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```